# Buddypress - Send New User Activation Link to Admin

Tags: users, buddypress, email

How do I send the new user activation link to my own email address instead of the user? Is there a simple function I can use to switch things out?

```
function bp_core_activation_signup_user_notification( $user, $user_email, $key, $meta ) {

$activate_url = bp_get_activation_page() . "?key=$key";
$activate_url = esc_url($activate_url);
$admin_email  = get_site_option( 'admin_email' );

if ( empty( $admin_email ) )
    $admin_email = 'support@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

// If this is an admin generated activation, add a param to email the
// user login details
$email = is_admin() ? '&e=1' : '';

$from_name       = ( '' == get_site_option( 'site_name' ) ) ? 'WordPress' : esc_html( get_site_option( 'site_name' ) );
$message_headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "From: \"{$from_name}\" <{$admin_email}>\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"" . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) . "\"\n";
$message         = sprintf( __( "Thanks for registering! To complete the activation of your account please click the following link:\n\n%1\$s\n\n", 'buddypress' ), $activate_url . $email );
$subject         = '[' . $from_name . '] ' . __( 'Activate Your Account', 'buddypress' );

// Send the message
$to      = apply_filters( 'bp_core_activation_signup_user_notification_to',   $user_email, $user, $user_email, $key, $meta );
$subject = apply_filters( 'bp_core_activation_signup_user_notification_subject', $subject, $user, $user_email, $key, $meta );
$message = apply_filters( 'bp_core_activation_signup_user_notification_message', $message, $user, $user_email, $key, $meta );

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $message_headers );

do_action( 'bp_core_sent_user_signup_email', $admin_email, $subject, $message, $user, $user_email, $key, $meta );

// Return false to stop the original WPMU function from continuing
return false;
```

}
if ( !is_admin() || ( is_admin() && empty( $_POST['noconfirmation'] ) ) )
    add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification', 'bp_core_activation_signup_user_notification', 1, 4 );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the code I would try something like this:

```
add_filter( 
    'bp_core_signup_send_validation_email_to', 
    'wpse_60858_catch_user_signup_mail' 
);

function wpse_60858_catch_user_signup_mail()
{
    // make sure to use a valid email. test it with different addresses
    return get_site_option( 'admin_email', 'fallback-address@example.com' );
}
```

This changes the `$to` part only.

Comment: I added this to my theme's functions and its not working :(

Comment: @Aliyah Maybe you didn’t the option `'admin_email'`? Try a hard coded email instead like `hello@example.com`.

Comment: Heres what I have : if ( empty( $admin_email ) )
  $admin_email = 'myemail@gmail.com';

Comment: Im not using wp_mail, Im using SMTP or whatever you call it. Could that be why its not working?

Comment: This function uses `wp_mail()`. Did you change that? You shouldn’t. Install a SMTP plugin instead that hooks into `wp_mail`.

Comment: Im using a SMTP plugin and it works perfectly. Problem is, I can't get the activation key to send to the admin in buddypress. Aargh! I'll try again. PS: Do I add this to my theme functions or a custom functions file in plugins dir?

Comment: `functions.php` or a plugin. A plugin suits better, but it works in both.

Comment: Ok im about to try again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4545/discussion-between-aliyah-and-toscho)